# directory listing command error after install google-authenticator on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, ls, sshd, pam

## Status

- CentOS 7.5.1804 (Core)
- Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64

## Problem

After I installed and setting `google-authenticator` packages, weird authentication related message keep shown when I use directory listing command on user's home directory.

I've tested on another owned directory but nothing happend unless home directory.

`ls`, `dir` and authentication works fine but still message are annoying me :\

```
$ ls
cannot be satisfied by enabled authentication method?OAqsq

$ ls -al
합계 208
drwx------   6 user user  4096 10월 15 10:06 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root      20 10월 10 12:23 .. cannot be satisfied by enabled authentication method?OAqsq

$ dir
cannot\ be\ satisfied\ by\ enabled\ authentication\ method\033OAqsq
```

## Logs

- There is no related error or message on `/var/log/secure` and `messages`
- `sshd -t` is okay

### /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

UsePAM yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
GSSAPIAuthentication no

AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes

AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive
```

#### /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth         required       pam_sepermit.so
#auth       substack     password-auth
...
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
auth       required     pam_google_authenticator.so nullok
```

Comment: That looks like a file with an uncommon filename to me, not an error message as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so dumb, there is file that named `cannot be satisfied by enabled authentication method?OAqsq` in my home directory.